# CSV to JSON using D3.JS

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, linechart

I have a csv file in the following format

```
type,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,.... // Upto 48
type1,54.69801915,84.4717406,81.87766667,66.48516667,...
type2,51.57399106,84.23170179,82.13950136,67.37540461,...
......
```

I wanna draw a line chart using this csv data with d3. Once I nest them using below code

```
d3.nest().key(function(d) { 
    return d.type; 
  }).entries(data);
```

My json looks as follow

```
{ key: "type1", values: […] }
```

and inside `values` it is just a single element array and the value of that is `{ 1: 54.69801915, 2: 84.4717406, 3: 81.87766667, … }`

But my expectation is that that would be a array something similar to

```
{ { 1: 54.69801915}, {2: 84.4717406}, {3: 81.87766667}, … }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Or how should I get my expected format?

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's the expected behaviour of `d3.nest()`.

If you want that structure you shared in your question, with `values` as an array of objects, I suggest you write your own nesting function.

Here is an example of code that does what you want, using `map` and `for...in`. It's neither elegant nor beautiful, it's purposely verbose to be easily understood (I'm using only a few columns and rows in your data):

```js
var csv = `type,1,2,3,4
type1,54.69801915,84.4717406,81.87766667,66.48516667
type2,51.57399106,84.23170179,82.13950136,67.37540461`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var nested = data.map(function(d) {
  var obj = {
    key: d.type,
    values: []
  };
  for (var prop in d) {
    if (prop !== "type") {
      obj.values.push({
        [prop]: d[prop]
      })
    }
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(nested)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Some additional comments:

- What yo have in your question is not a JSON, that's just a simple JavaScript object.
- What you call an *array* at the end of your question is neither an array nor an object, that's actually invalid.
- Finally, don't use numbers for your property names.